# How do I read a file from SVN after the file was removed?

Tags: svn, version-control

When I do:

```
svn ls -r 2200 demo/hello/
```

I can see a bunch of files:

```
greetings.xml
something.xml
world.xml
zoo.xml
```

A hundred revisions later, the `world.xml` file doesn't exist any longer.

I thought that in order to see the contents of a file from SVN, I simply use `svn cat` and specify the revision. However, neither:

```
svn cat -r 2200 demo/hello/world.xml
```

nor:

```
svn cat demo/hello/world.xml@2200
```

work in my case; both return:

> svn: E155010: The node '/home/user/src/demo/hello/world.xml' was not found.

So how do I read from SVN the contents of a file which existed long ago but doesn't exist any longer?